# Converting a 2d array to a 1d List, then back to a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays

In order to serialize a 2d array I am first flattening it like so:

```
InfoCell[,] cells = new InfoCell[size, size];
List<InfoCell> flattenedCells= new List<InfoCell>();

foreach(InfoCell infoCell in cells )
{
    flattenedCells.Add(infoCell);
}
```

Knowing the size of the 2d array, how can I convert this 1d List back into a 2d array?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. -- Just allocate another 2d array and do a loop?

Comment: The question is how do I convert this 1d List back into a 2d array. I save the 1d List when I exit the session (since I cannot serialize a 2d array), when I load back up I want to populate a 2d array using the 1d List.

Comment: You'd need some sort of logic on how you want to convert the 1d back to 2d... really dependent on your structure.   Is your initial 2d array always going to be a square array?  AKA size by size?

Comment: Serialize to what? Converting 1 <-> 2 dimensions isn't your real problem.

Comment: If so, and you know your length is a square length... Then you can figure out the dimensions of your 2d array,  -- and per "size" number of entries of the 1d array, -- thats 1 row or 1 column of the 2d array

Comment: Like I said in the question I know the size of the 2d array. In this scenario its always size by size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var array = new string[rowsSize, columnSize];
var list = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < rowsSize; i++)
{
   for (var j = 0; j < columnSize; j++)
   {
      list.Add(array[i,j]);
   }   
}

var newArray = new string[rowsSize, columnSize];
for (var i = 0; i < rowsSize; i++)
{
   for (var j = 0; j < columnSize; j++)
   {
       var index = i * columnSize + j;
       newArray[i, j] = list[index];
   }   
}
```